# Accessing the browsing history of iphone using webkit private framework

Tags: ios, ios5, webkit, iphone-3gs

Hi I request please read the question completely before marking it as duplicate.

I am trying to get the iphone browsing history by using Webkit private framework.I get the headers for it from the github site. But I am not getting which headers or which methods to use to accomplish my task. I tried with the following code but its not returning anything not even null.

```
WebHistory *history=[WebHistory optionalSharedHistory];
NSDate *now = [NSDate date];
//id date;
NSArray *arr = [history orderedItemsLastVisitedOnDay:now];
NSLog(@"%@",[history allItems]);
```

I am writing in house app so i don't mind with this private framework. But i just can't go for jailbreaking. Please guide me the right way.

Answer (score 0):

In order for the optionalSharedHistory method to return anything but null it must be instantiated and set like so in a place that's convenient in your application. Like a root view controller or the AppDelegate.

```
// Create a shared WebHistory object
WebHistory *myHistory = [[WebHistory alloc] init];
[WebHistory setOptionalSharedHistory:myHistory];
```

Hope this helps!